# Faster way of implementing-To assign label for every pixel

Tags: matlab

I have a depth map(with some NaN values) and a Color segmented image(CSI). I have assigned label to the segments of CSI. I have to pick non NaN pixels from depth map and assign it with the label(which was calculated in CSI), as both are of same size so they must be congruent in position/location of pixel. I have written a code in Matlab, but it is working very slow. Below is my code: -

```
label = bwlabel(seg);        %% seg is CSI 
num = max(max(label));       %% num will store the number of segments created.

[a,b] = size(d_map);         %% d_map is depth map
for i=1:a                    %% loop along width and heigh of depth map
  for j=1:b
    if isnan(d_map(i,j))     %% leave the NaN values
        continue;
    else                     %% After having one non NaN value, starts loop from 1  till number of labels
      for k=1:num            
         cell = (label == k);  %% assign every label number to image cell one-by one
            values = cell(i,j); 
            if values == 0      %% choose only the segmented part, i.e. with value ==1 only.
               continue;
               else
                   display(k);
                   break;
               end
           end
         end
      end
    end
```

If anyone suggest any faster way of doing it. That would be great!!. 
Thank You for your help. My next step would be to create vector of vectors or cell arrays for the number of labels and place the non NaN pixel values of depth map in the cell array of respected label.

Comment: So you want the depth values for a given label?

Comment: What does `cell = (label == k)` create, a logical vector with only one true value or possibly multiple true values?

Comment: @Suever - It's little confusing -- I have a depth map and its pixel values, I have label for color image segments, both depth map and color segmented image are of same size, So, I am reading location of pixel from depth map, checking to which label it belongs using color image segments. The code mentioned above works good, but is very slow. I want a faster way.

Comment: @Akash But you aren't actually *assigning* any outputs.

Comment: @Daniel - `cell = (label == k)` : as k increase from label 1 to n number of label, for every value it stores that segment to which it assigns that label. Suppose, k=1, so label 1 will be assign to cell (i.e. a segmented part with label num 1)  and then I can process with that later on as you can see ahead

Comment: @Suever - No, I am just displaying the segment number here, I will have further processing to do, but here I just want to see that any pixel of depth map belongs to which label segmented part. For example if at i=8, j =135 of depth map, I will look through different labels, whichever label has that pixel location, that label will be assign to that location.

Comment: "whichever label has that pixel location, that label will be assign to that location" What label goes where? You're reusing "label" and "location" to mean different things in the same sentence. How can we understand what you're trying to do? You've got a location `(8,135)`. You check the value of `my_value = label(8,135)`. Now, what do you do with `my_value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the code is really inefficient:

```
     cell = (label == k);
     [m,n] = size(cell);
     for p=1:m
       for q=1:n
           values = cell(p,q);
           if values == 0
               continue;
           elseif p == i && q == j
                  display(k);
                  break;
           end
       end
     end
```

Here you are only doing something for the case p==i and q==j but you iterate all other cases.

```
cell = (label == k);
values = cell(i,j);
if not(values == 0);
    display(k);
end
```

Which further translates to

```
if label(i,j)==k
    display(k)
end
```

I assume your code does not do what you expect it to do, I recommend to add comments to the code and explain what it should do.

Comment: Oh sorry, I had to put `cell(p,q)` instead of  `cell(i,j)`. I copied it wrong. "i" and "j" are the pixel location of depth map. and "p" and "q" are the pixel location of the cell(image of the segmented part that shows which label number is assigned to that segmented part).

Comment: @Akash: It does not matter, as I mentioned your code only displays something for the p=i and q=j case.

Comment: I guess you are not clear with what I am trying to say. p and q are location of cell image, and i and j are of depth map. They both are of two different image with same size. Using same pixel location, I am trying to find the label number. I have explained a little more in the code right now. Hope it will make it more clearer.

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do and I still don't understand it. I just looked at your code from a formal perspective and noticed it does a lot of useless iterations. Try both your loop version and my simplified version, for any input they print the same results.

Comment: Thank You for your help. I understood what you were trying to say. I have deleted the second loop. But still it will not produce the same result. See in the image named **cell** you have 1 and 0 values, I needed only that part with 1 value. I hope you understand. But I am pretty sure that it will not produce the same, but thanks for the help as with your help, I noticed that there is no use of second loop and now it is little faster.